# How to delete unused records from a table when those records no longer act as foreign keys to a "linked" table

Tags: database, sqlite, foreign-keys

**Background information:**
I am trying to normalize an SQLite database.
The database has a table called "image" containing a field called "filepath" which stores the absolute filepath of the image. However, for large media collections with several nested directory levels, the size of the database increases.
So I now plan to create a new table called "paths" to store the directory paths alone. "Image" table will simply store the foreign key to "paths" table. "Image" table also has a field called "title" using which I can reconstruct the absolute filepath for use in my software

**Question:**
How do I delete a record from the "paths" table once that record no longer acts as a foreign key to any record in the "image" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement deletes all such records:

```
DELETE FROM paths
WHERE pathID NOT IN (SELECT pathID
                     FROM image)
```

Alternatively, if you want to do the check just after you've deleted an `image` record with a specific `pathID`, use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM paths
WHERE pathID = ?
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT pathID
                  FROM image
                  WHERE pathID = ?)
```